# Middle click with trackpad in MBP and Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, mojave

I want to setup the middle click with a MBP using the trackpad.

The middle click is very useful to me since I can open/close tabs, can use 2 clipboards like linux (select and middle click to paste, besides regular copy/paste). I was using very well this middle click with High Sierra and the MagicPrefs app, but with Mojave this started working terribly bad and had to uninstall it. Have tried another paid app named Multitouch but does not even work as MagicPrefs.

Do you know how I can setup middle click in Mojave?

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro11,3
Processor Name: Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:    2.5 GHz
```

Comment: Coudl you tell us what Mac is it. Also what TrackPad model.

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's the built-in trackpad, I added more information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MagicPrefs is no longer supported nor updated.

[image]

Possible replacement for it is the Better_Touch_Tool.

You can try it risk free for 45 days.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, +1 for that. I noticed this is $20, by chance do you know a free or cheaper alternative?

Comment: I would not buy the Life Time license for $20, the Standard is only $6.50. Consider the last version (Free) worked for 5 years.

Comment: I tested it and works perfectly well. Anyway, do you know another free alternative like MagicPrefs?

Comment: sorry, that I do not know, that works with Mojave.